# How to have a vaadin component to choose date and time both

Tags: java, datetime, vaadin

I am using `PopupDateField` component of vaadin and it only allows to select the Day not with time. Is there any other component in vaadin that this capability is or is there any way I can change the PopupDateField to support time choosing?

This is my code now

```
        PopupDateField popupDateFieldScheduled = new PopupDateField();
        popupDateFieldScheduled.setImmediate(false);
        popupDateFieldScheduled.setWidth("-1px");
        popupDateFieldScheduled.setHeight("-1px");
        popupDateFieldScheduled.setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The default resolution of a DateField in Vaadin 7 is Day. You can configure it by using [DateField#setReolution](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/DateField.html#setResolution%28com.vaadin.shared.ui.datefield.Resolution%29), i.e. `popupDateFieldScheduled.setResolution(Resolution.SECOND)`